# Подвинуть border относительно картинки

Tags: css, css3, вёрстка

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Хочу сделать так. Понятно, что чтобы выдвинуть на передний план, нужно добавить `z-index`. Но как сделать подобный `border` относительно изображения?

Comment: Нужно добавить такой border картинке?

Comment: В идеале - да, верно. Можно просто фиксированный, размер картинки не важен.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Решение через `border` и использование `div`:

```css
.image {
  position: relative;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background-image: url("https://graph.facebook.com/625308780945294/picture?type=large");
}

.image:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  border: 2px solid #c745bc;
  left: 20%;
  top: 20%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="image">
</div>
```

Comment: В итоге сделал, отталкиваясь от этого. Только часть стилей сменил на `left: 30%;  top: -5%;  width: 75%;  height: 95%;`

Comment: @TimurMusharapov Без проблем, это просто пример и тут абсолютно каждая цифра на ваше усмотрение. Разве только `z-index` должен быть отрицателен.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov, не могли бы вы добавить меня в друзья в одном из из соц. сетей указанных в моём профиле? Мне было бы интересно пообщаться с вами на разные темя по поводу разработки сайтов. А то совсем не с кем поговорить

Answer (score 6):

Можно сделать с помощью тени, но этот способ сработает, если только на фоне сплошной цвет:

```css
img {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  box-shadow: 16px 16px 0px #fff, 18px 18px 0px #c745bc, 18px 14px 0px #c745bc, 14px 18px 0px #c745bc;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://graph.facebook.com/625308780945294/picture?type=large">
```

Comment: О, здорово, пример понятен! Спасибо.

Comment: Прекрасный, лаконичный ответ, не требует дополнительного блока и работает с тэгом `img`. Единственное если бы `box-shadow` можно было бы возможно более изящно выразить, то было бы идеально. И ещё вопрос: а если фон не сплошной цвет? На что это `16px 16px 0px #fff` менять?

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov, если не сплошной цвет, то проблема) Тогда надо уже с дополнительными тегами

Comment: @Yuri Да просто укажите это ограничение в ответе (если конечно вам не трудно). А если не брать это в расчёт, ответ очень оригинален.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov, добавил. Ваш способ отличный, только жалко, что там кода многовато в итоге )

Answer (score 4):

**transform: translate():**

```css
div {
  position: relative;
  padding: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 20px;
  background: #eee;
}

div:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  border: 2px solid red;
  transform: translate(15px, -15px);
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div><img src="http://put-k-uspehy.ru/wp-content/uploads/2011/12/elka_na_sayt.gif" alt=""></div>
```

Answer (score 3):

как вариант - размести изображение в div установи border у div`а и смести img относительно div через position или transform

https://jsfiddle.net/1fve7q00/

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  position: relative;
}

img {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  left: -10px;
  top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="http://lomets.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/Stephanie-Beck-3.png" alt="">
</div>
```